# Values empty on CSV file

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

I am able to generate CSV file from XML file using XSLT, but the only header of XML file header is only showing on CSV file. The Values are not showing up.

**Here is my java code:-**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class xml2csv {
     public static void main() throws Exception {
            File stylesheet = new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/out.xslt");
            File xmlSource = new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/out.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

            StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
            Source source = new DOMSource(document);
            Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/out.csv"));
            transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
        }
}
```

**the XML file:-**

```
<root>
    <header>Symbol</header>
    <row>NIFTY 50</row>
    <row>LUPIN</row>
    <header>Open</header>
    <row>9,670.35</row>
    <row>1,082.90</row>
    <header>High</header>
    <row>9,684.25</row>
    <row>1,137.00</row>
</root>
```

**XSLT file:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        Symbol,Open,High
        <xsl:for-each select="//header">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Symbol, ',', Open, ',', High)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, I am getting only header of XML using this XSLT, where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you should re-format your XML first and than according to that update your XSLT file too.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output. -- The reason why your attempt fails is that `<xsl:value-of select="concat(Symbol,',',Open,',',High)"/>` does not select anything, because your XML does not have any elements named `Symbol` or `Open ` or `High`.

Comment: P.S. Do you have control over the structure of your XML? If I am guessing correctly at what it represents, it's very poorly constructed and it will take a lot of work to get the expected CSV out of it.

Answer (score 1):

If I am guessing correctly at what you're trying to accomplish here, you will need to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>Symbol,Open,High&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="count(row) div 3" />
    <xsl:for-each select="row[position() &lt;= $n]">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../row[$n + $i]"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../row[2 * $n + $i]"/>        
        <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
Symbol,Open,High
"NIFTY 50","9,670.35","9,684.25"
"LUPIN","1,082.90","1,137.00"
```

I have added quotes around the values because some of them contain commas - but I did not handle the possibility of some them containing a quote.

---

As I mentioned in a comment to your question, this could be a lot easier if your XML were structured in a more friendly way.